# How much Azure Automation account will cost if we use for few minutes daily?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

We are thinking to enable Azure automation account. We have 2 VMs and account will be used ***only*** to start(at 9AM) and stop(at 6PM) two VMs daily.
*Assuming we have 2VMs, can you please estimate monthly cost for this automation account?*

I checked Azure calculator, it's showing some $ per minute after 500min but i am not able to understand how much it will cost if account is used only for few minutes daily. Which minutes it will consider? A month has 60*24*30=43200 minutes and does this mean it will cost $x*(43200-500)?
Our budget is limited so details of the expense will help.

Comment: if someone voting for closing, please at least help a brother with answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the documentation correctly, basically you will be charged for the total number of minutes you ran your jobs across all automation account in a month (first 500 minutes are free).

So let's assume that it takes 5 minutes each to run start and stop VM jobs. Then in a day you consumed 10 minutes and in a month you consumed 300 minutes (assuming 30 month day). In this case you will not be charged anything because you're below 500 minute limit.

Now let's assume that it takes 10 minutes each to run start and stop VM jobs. Then you would be consuming 600 minutes in a month. In this case you will be charged for 100 minutes (as first 500 minutes are free).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i see, i assumed so as well. But the scheduler will run forever - will that be added to the cost? Have you ever use it?

Comment: I haven’t used it, sorry.